# How to send a PATCH HTTP Callout from Apex to Salesforce Tooling REST API

Tags: apex, tooling-api, httprequest, patch

**BACKGROUND**

I using Apex to get a list of `FlowDefinition` and would like to update the `activeVersionNumber` via using a PATCH request.

**QUESTION**

How can I achieve this using Apex if it does not support the PATCH verb??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `?_HttpMethod=PATCH` in the request URL.

```
public static HttpResponse makeHttpCallout(String url, String method, String body, Map<String,String> headers){

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();

    if(method == 'PATCH'){
        request.setMethod('POST');
        url += '?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
    } else {
        request.setMethod(method);
    }

    request.setEndpoint(url);

    if(String.isNotBlank(body)){
        request.setBody(body);
    }

    if(headers != null){
        for(String key : headers.keySet()){
            request.setHeader(key, headers.get(key));
        }
    }

   return http.send(request);
}
```